# Can Disney claim Florida has passed and is pursuing Bills of Attainder?

Tags: united-states, attainder

The State of Florida seems to be in a protracted battle with Disney.  The state has legislated in the direction of Disney, and continues to do so
(https://www.wfla.com/news/florida/desantis-speaking-at-reedy-creek-administration-building/).

Despite the fact that there might be real arguments that such legislation is for the well-being of the state, the dialog surrounding Reedy Creek issues, including statements coming out of the State, seems to provide a solid argument that the motivation for such legislation is to punish Disney for voicing objection to recent policy decisions in the State.

Assuming that as a given, for the moment (though that's, at the least, arguable), doesn't that provide Disney with the argument that these are Bills of Attainder?

Comment: The law that shifted Reedy Creek into Florida State control had a loophole that Reedy Creek and Disney exploited (that is being generous.  It's arguable that what Disney did was straight up illegal).   The new legislation is set to close the loophole, which became apparent when Disney exploited the loophole.   It doesn't target Disney, but every special district like Reedy Creek that fell under the initial legislation.  Disney/Reedy Creek just happened to be the only organization to abuse the loophole.

Comment: @hszmv Obviously, I'm not a lawyer, but it would seem to me like if something illegal were done in exploiting the loophole, it was done by the Reedy Creek District before the takeover, not Disney.

Comment: Loopholes are always legal.  It's debated if what Disney did was a loophole or actually illegal.   Either way, the new law will likely be written to close the loophole and void all contracts that exploited the loophole.

Comment: @hszmv It was my understanding that Reedy Creek was by some crazy coincidence the only special district affected by the initial legislation.

Comment: There's also a valid question of whether what the state did was legal, since it blatantly targeted Disney in retaliation for 1st Amendment-protected speech on a hot political issue.

Comment: @AndrewRay Reedy Creek was hardly the only special district that fell under the law, it was just the most visible.  The Reedy Creek Improvement District (RCID) was actually granted because at time, Walt Disney wanted to use the land to build a functional city (This was the original plan for EPCOT.  The model of the proposed city can be seen on the People Mover in the Magic Kingdom).   At the time it was granted, no one in the FL legislature knew that the RCID was Disney... it was at the time a bunch of shell corporations.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.clickorlando.com/news/local/2022/04/20/special-district-bill-will-leave-orange-osceola-taxpayers-with-disney-debt-democrats-say/) article there are only five other districts affected by the legislation, out of almost 2000 special districts which exist; and *"The bill allows the districts to apply to be reestablished on or after June 1, 2023."* So presumably the other five districts affected will apply to be re-established and their applications will be approved, given that DeSantis has stated several times that the purpose of the bill is to target Disney.

Answer (score 2):

Legislatures are free to declare illegal whatever they want (within Constitutional limitations, obviously).  A bill of attainder declares a defendant guilty without trial.  Targeting a company with laws isn't particularly noteworthy, this is done all the time, usually to the company's benefit.

Nothing Florida is doing would be considered a bill of attainder.  Special conditions that have been set by the state are always available to be re-legislated.

Comment: https://scholarlycommons.law.hofstra.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1231&context=faculty_scholarship  suggests "Matters involving a bill of attainder law is where a legislative action is directed against an individual or a group of individuals with the intent to inflict punishment", which is somewhat different from your working definition.  There's a fair public record surrounding recent Disney/Florida interactions suggesting that the Reedy Park legislation was to punish Disney.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The definition cited is over broad. A bill of attainder imposes a criminal punishment without a trial on an identified individual.

Comment: @ohwilleke US vs Lovett was struck down ax a bill of attainder by SCOTUS,  but had no criminal punishment.

Comment: @ohwilleke Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_attainder), *"the Lovett Court said that a bill of attainder 1) specifically identified the people to be punished; 2) imposed punishment; and 3) did so without benefit of judicial trial."* At least to me, it seems quite possible to argue that all three of these conditions are met. If (as in *Lovett*) denial of federal employment is a punishment, then denial of other things ─ even things which are not rights, as federal employment isn't ─ could also count as punishment. I'd love to see an answer addressing the *Lovett* test.

Comment: @ScottSeidman the punishment was the prohibition on federal employment.  If you think that is not "criminal punishment" then consider [18 USC 201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/201).

Answer (score 1):

At question here is whether Disney was punished by an act of the Florida Legislature.  Lets look at basically how this happened.  At first the legislature voted to strip Reedy Creek of its special designation.  Once they realized that this would shift the burden of bond payment to the local counties to the tune of billions, they repealed the law that stripped Reedy Creek of its special designation.  They then passed a law dissolving the Reedy Creek Board that was appointed by Disney.  Before that board was seated, Disney held public meetings in accordance with Florida transparency laws and changed their by-laws as to what power the board would have.  Again this was done above board just no one seemed to notice.  This was signed off on by the former board which was still legally the board for Reedy Creek.  Now that we know this, did the legislature make *all* the boards of special tax districts submit to a board appointed by the Governor to make business decisions?  No, just Disney.  Also, the Governors own words show that this was a retaliatory action.  Disney has an incredibly strong case here and if I had to chose which one to represent...it would easily be Disney.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is fine as an argument assuming facts, but most of them are disputed by the parties involved.